# type error this.service.newPerson is not a fucntion angular unit testing jasmine and jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, components, ts-jest

**data-detail.spec.ts**

```
let component: PersonDetailComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PersonDetailComponent>;

    const personServiceMock: PersonService = {getStringForRelation: jest.fn()} as any;
    const dateAdapterMock: DateAdapter<Date> = {setLocale: jest.fn()} as any;
    const NotificationServiceMock: DatevNotificationService = {} as any;
    const apiServiceMock: ApiService = {} as any;
    const clientServiceMock: ClientService = {} as any;
    it('btnadddata für Kind', () => {
                component.isNewPerson = true;
        const nodeDataArray: Array<go.ObjectData> = [
            {
                idPerson: 1,
                s: 'M',
                key: 1,
                personDetail: {
                    firstname: 'Vorname',
                    name: 'Nachname',
                    gender: PersonDetail.GenderEnum.IsMale,
                    isAlive: true,
                },
                quotasRelation: {
                    relationToOwner: QuotasRelation.RelationToOwnerEnum.Kind,
                },
                asset: {}
            }
        ];
        const relation: RelationToOwnerEnum = 'Kind';
        const mid = 1;
        const newPerson: Person = {
            idPerson: 1,
            // @ts-ignore
            key: 1,
            personDetail: {
                firstname: 'test',
                name: 'test1',
                gender: 'IsMale',
                idMother: 1,
                idFather: null,
                idSpouse: null,
                birthdate: null,
                isAlive: true,
            },
            quotasRelation: {
                relationToOwner: relation,
            },
            asset: {}
        };
        // const id = component.person.
        // const mid = component.person.personDetail.idMother;
        // const firstname = component.person.personDetail.firstname;
        // const gender = component.person.personDetail.gender;
        component.person.quotasRelation.relationToOwner = relation;
        component.person.idPerson = mid;
        component.nodeDataArray = nodeDataArray;
        component.btnAddPerson_Click(relation);
        console.log();
        component.personService.newPerson(1, 'test', 'test1', 'IsMale', mid, undefined, 
        undefined, relation).personDetail.idMother = mid;
        expect(newPerson).toEqual(component.addChildToPerson(component.selectedNode.data));
    });
```

**person-detail.component.ts**

```
btnAddPerson_Click(relation: RelationToOwnerEnum): void {
        let newPerson: Person = null;
        if (relation === RelationToOwnerEnum.Kind) {
            newPerson = this.addChildToPerson(this.selectedNode.data);
        } else if (relation === RelationToOwnerEnum.Gatte) {
            newPerson = this.addSpouseToPerson(this.selectedNode.data);
        } else if (relation === RelationToOwnerEnum.BruderSchwester) {
            newPerson = this.addSiblingToPerson(this.selectedNode.data);
        } else if (relation === RelationToOwnerEnum.Vater) {
            newPerson = this.addParentToPerson(this.selectedNode.data);
        }
        if (newPerson) {
            this.isNewPerson = true;
            this.person = newPerson;
        }
    }

    addChildToPerson(parent: Person): Person {
        let fid: number;
        let mid: number;
        console.log('person', parent);
        if (parent.personDetail.idSpouse === undefined) {
            if (parent.personDetail.gender === PersonDetail.GenderEnum.IsMale) {
                fid = parent.idPerson;
                mid = undefined;
            } else {
                fid = undefined;
                mid = parent.idPerson;
            }
        } else if (parent.personDetail.gender === PersonDetail.GenderEnum.IsMale) {
            fid = parent.idPerson;
            mid = parent.personDetail.idSpouse;
        } else {
            fid = parent.personDetail.idSpouse;
            mid = parent.idPerson;
        }
        console.log('addChildToPerson Vater-Key Mutter-Key', fid, mid);
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        return this.personService.newPerson(this.getNextId(this.nodeDataArray), '', 
        parent.personDetail.name, null, mid, fid, -1, 
        QuotasRelation.RelationToOwnerEnum.Kind);
    }
```

**person.service.ts**

```
 export class PersonService {
    
        constructor() {
        }
    
        private readonly DUMMYSPOUSE = 'DummySpouse';
    
        private static getRelationWithGender(gender: GenderEnum, male: string, female: string, 
            diverse: string): string {
            return gender && gender === GenderEnum.IsMale ? male : gender && gender === 
            GenderEnum.IsFemale ? female : diverse;
    
        }
    
        public newPerson(
            id: number,
            firstname: string,
            name: string,
            gender: PersonDetail.GenderEnum,
            idMother: number,
            idFather: number,
            idSpouse: number,
            relation: QuotasRelation.RelationToOwnerEnum
        ): Person {
            return {
                idPerson: id,
                // @ts-ignore
                key: id,
                personDetail: {
                    firstname,
                    name,
                    gender,
                    idMother,
                    idFather,
                    idSpouse,
                    birthdate: null,
                    isAlive: true,
                },
                quotasRelation: {
                    relationToOwner: relation,
                },
                asset: {}
            };
           }
```

> i have tried several ways but i am not able to identify the error and
> i know that newPerson is not a function but how to oversome this
> error? I am new to testing , please help me.

> how can i overcome this problem do i have to mock the method as new
> person is not a method i cannot do that either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**just add the function into the mckservice that is**

```
const personServiceMock: PersonService = {getStringForRelation: jest.fn(), 
newPerson: jest.fn()} as any
```

which was very simple but yet very difficult to configure as i am really new to testing but i somwhow configured.